# Wondering how to get inexpensive 10 mA power supplies for electrochemistry

Tags: power-supply

As part of my graduate research on electrochemistry, I'm looking for a way to have 10 or 20 inexpensive, low amperage, constant current power supplies that simply hold at 10 mA with reasonable accuracy, +/- 1 mA.

My first thought was to purchase a bunch of wall chargers [like these ones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JUFFO6Q), cut the jack off it, split the wires, attach a 10 ohm resistor inline then attach some leads. Then I would buy a power strip and plug all of them in and have one "power supply" per electrochem experiment I'm running. But I'm not sure if that would work because I'm unsure if these adapters are constant current or constant voltage. I definitely need CC.

Even if I did make this small army of power supplies, how would I go about measuring them for accuracy? I'm not sure how good my cheap $10 multimeter is at measuring ~10 mA while the electrochem is running, and I'm not sure how much measuring the system affects the current while it's being measured. If anyone has a suggestion for a good multimeter/current measuring device at such low currents, I'd love to hear it.

The answers so far are very helpful. Thank you all very much. I have a lot of reading to do to learn everything presented so far.

Edit in response to expected voltages and chemistry details:

I ran a solvent system yesterday which required 5-7 V (currently using cheap, 10 A power supplies for our initial runs), but today I have another solvent which requires 22 V. I don't think the experiments will require anything more than 25 V.

The electrochem experiments involve using rare-earth metals to make/break chemical bonds. We'll be running them with 5 - 20 mL of solvent in a divided cell reaction flask using organic solvents like acetonitrile and acetic acid, and organic salts as electrolytes. The divided cell has a cathode on one side and an anode on the other, separated by a fine frit. The experiments will run for at least an hour, up to 24 hours in some cases.

Comment: What range of voltages/resistances do you expect?

Comment: (1) Vast majority of consumer power supplies are constant voltage.  The only type of consumer power supplies with constant current output that comes to mind are LED power supplies.  (2) Could you describe your electrochemistry experiment in more details, please?  (3) I'd like to second the question about the range of voltages.

Comment: If you can have one common terminal (one side of the current sources or sinks) you can use one power supply and many simple current regulators.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include an answer to @W5VO's question in the first comment? This could have an effect on the answer.

Comment: Any DMM in current mode will give you pretty accurate readings, since the "burden voltage" will be negligible relative to supply voltage.

Comment: [It would appear that 10V is a starting point.](https://www.ameteksi.com/products/potentiostats/multichannel/parstat-mc) Commercial units operate at 10V.  30V appears to be the maximum.  So at 10V, the expected resistance is therefore less than 1000ohm (10V) or less than 3000 ohm (30V)

Comment: The LM317 requires about 3V difference between input and output to operate.  This reduces your working voltage range to 9V, and the maximum resistance to 900 ohm.  Also, 10mA is at the lower limit of its range.  It might not regulate well.  The LT3042 only loses a few hundred millivolts from input tp output, leaving with over 11V and over 1100 ohms.  It is also designed for low current use.

Comment: How much *power* do you need to deliver?

Comment: You have two answers with good suggestions, for LM317, and for LT3042, both will work in your application. The former costs pennies, the latter costs pounds, that may help your choice.

Comment: @JRE - The data sheet gives 5 mA as a lower limit for using the 317 as a current source.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: It says the lowest current for proper  regulation is 5mA (typical) 10mA(worst case). So, most of the time a 10mA regulator built from an LM317 ought to work - except when it doesn't.

Comment: Meter:  Beware the $10 bargain DVMs but any decent meter will work fine.  I love Fluke, but the good Chinese meters have gotten better and better.

Comment: Answered questions about voltages and some chem details. Thanks all.

Comment: If you need 25V, the 12V supply you linked to will not be a good choice. It will be much easier if you don't need to boost voltage. So look for some kind of supply that can produce 30V and use the ideas elsewhere in this thread.

Answer (score 10):

The cheapest way is to buy some LM317 voltage regulators, and some 124 ohm resistors. The data sheet for the [LM317](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM317L.pdf) will show you how to connect them, and parts cost will be about 50 cents per channel. Plus, of course, a DC power supply of at least 3 volts greater than the electrochem potential, and at least 200 mA for 20 channels.

Comment: +1, yes, LM317 is a classics for 10 mA, works like a charm. Maybe some trimpot is needed to compensate for 50uA of adjustment pin current,

Comment: NIST is redefining all metrology values based on universal constants to improve the present 7 significant figures.  LM317L is about 10 cents in bulk (300pc)

Comment: @AliChen - OP gave a 1% error margin, and that's 100 uA.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist - I used digikey 1 unit price, about 40 cents.

Comment: Sounds right...

Comment: I read 10% tolerance wanted

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist - Right you are. I _knew_ there was a reason I wasn't worried about errors.

Comment: The TL431 has the potential to be even cheaper, although an external pass transistor would be required.

Answer (score 8):

A better way would be to use a wall-wart connected to one of these:

An LT3042 constant current regulator

They are low noise and easy to adjust with one resistor to set the current.

[image]

You can get an LT3042 on a *[dev board](http://www.analog.com/en/products/power-management/current-sources/lt3092.html#product-evaluationkit).*

You can vary the current from 0 to 200 mA and it takes a 2 to 40 V input. You could measure the current with a picoammeter if you have the money. If you don't then just use a regular DMM. What it will come down to is accuracy and how accurate you need the current measurement. The accuracy can be found by going to the manufacturer's website and locating the specifications or buy downloading the datasheet.

[image]

Comment: @W5VO 10 mA  30% ?

Comment: @Tony Ewww.. that was not the part I thought I was looking at...

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmDivm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All you need is a current mirror.

All the same transistors. In 100pc < 10 cents/channel, if you know how.

### Sources of error.

- Noise ? use good EMI design practice
- Actual mirror is less by 2*hFE/R+emitter so increasing by same cancels this error. e.g.  If hFE ~ 100 this cancels a known 2% error by adding a 2 Ohm resistor.
- Similarily if hFE differs by 2:1 value between transistors, Imirror output has  1% error.
- R emitter tolerance in error, so use 1% or 0.1% matched arrays in SIP/DIP package etc.
- Set 10mA using Ohm's Law for R Ref